# Pagination in Oracle with dynamic query

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

I have a query that returns large amount of data. When users search for data in larger date ranges It can come up to 5 millions records, and when that happens app freezes for certain amount of time.

So I decided to do a pagination of query result, but I'm trying to do that without any DB changes. Let me explain:

I have a stored procedure for retrieving all data, with dynamic SQL. Input parameters are 3 :

- Varchar for number of Select case (to choose which select should be executed),
- and 2 other Varchar parameters that select fields and condition of query, in other words - one before **FROM** and one after **WHERE** clause. **These two parameters matter in this question.**

In example, my procedure for calling query looks like this:

> **first_parameter** || ' FROM (...here is my query where all possible fields are selected with joins, db links etc.... ) WHERE ' ||
>   **second_parameter**

So, I can modify start and end of query, and now I would like to modify It to enable pagination too, for let's say max 1.000 records at a time.

I have tried to modify It in C# by adding a **rownum** in **first_parameter** along with selected fields

> (**Select rownum, field1,field2** etc...)

, and using

> **rownum < 1000** in a **WHERE clause**

. This actually works, but for a pagination I would need also to tell what row for start and end, like

> **WHERE rownum > 1000 AND rownum < 2000**

, but this doesn't work.

How can I do this in Oracle 11g, where OFFSET is not available, can somebody show me ? I would prefer a solution without changing query inside of parameters If possible, since I can send everything I want into both parameters in question from C# in code (Varchar values ofcourse).

P.S. : I have never done a pagination so forgive me If I wrote some silly things ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to calculate *row number* for each row, e.g.

```
with ycq as
  -- your current query goes here
  (select col1, 
          col2, ..., 
       row_number() over (order by col1) rn         --> this is new ...
   from ...
   where ...
  )
select y.col1, 
       y.col2,
       ...
from ycq y
where y.rn between :lower_value and :upper_value    --> ... and is used here
order by y.some_col
```

Comment: thanks for this, It works. However, query executing is now even slower, bump. I'll try without order by, I guess here is the problem.

Comment: I changed your **row_number() over** with a simple **rownum** without any order by, and now query executes fast. But is that correct, will Oracle allways return different rows when I will specify different lower/upper parameter value **without order by** ?

Comment: There's no guarantee; it might, but it will probably not return rows in the same order. The only way to make sure is to use ORDER BY clause.

Comment: yes that is what I'm afraid of. But this way query executes very slow, 1 second against 58 with order by. Though I used date range for 5 millions of records, I have to test for more ussual date ranges.

Comment: Perhaps you should think it over. Who wants to scroll through 5 million rows, even on pages that contain 1000 rows? 5000 pages? That's way to much. Maybe, if you apply additional condition(s), number of rows returned will be much lower and pagination will make sense (and query I suggested will work faster).

Comment: yes I need to think about all. But your suggestion also gives me another problem, in WHERE clause. I select fields in first_parameter, and then I need to include those fields in WHERE clause again, only this time with "y." for aliases. It can be done though, just a little too much coding. Why doesn't this work by simply adding "**and rownum between :lower_value and :upper_value
       order by some_col**" in WHERE clause? That would easen me everything.... This way I can get result when I enter e.g. **lower_value=1, upper_value=1000**, but not **lower_value=1000, upper_value=2000**.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? Because Oracle designed it so. Documentation says: "Conditions testing for ROWNUM values greater than a positive integer are always false" (which is what `between` does in `rownum >= :lower_value`).

Comment: Ok I understand. Meanwhile I tested your suggestion and It works. Not quite fast as I hoped, but still time reduced from almost 8 minutes to 6 seconds - for 1.000 records, which is enormously better. Thanks for all explanations and answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For true pagination, you should look into [Oracle REST Data Services](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/rest.html) (ORDS) - It's free, easy to set up, and has pagination built in.

Comment: I'll take a closer look when I'll have more time than now, It looks complicated. Though what exactly is this, just some sort of a DB plug-in or web specific feature ? I need solution for desktop application only.

Comment: It's not part of the database, it's a separate product, but free. It makes it easy to set up web services in front of an Oracle database. Long story short is that it turn queries into JSON output, and also handles parameters and pagination easily. Something to consider for the future maybe.